# C++: "Launch failed. Binary not found." error whilst implementing a doubly-linked list with a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, doubly-linked-list

FYI: Using Eclipse Juno as my IDE.

My goal with this program is to basically simulate a bank account, holding on to customer information using a linked list and multiple classes. As of right now, the program compiles fine, however I get a binary error when I try to run it. I tested other programs to see if they would launch and they're all fine. How do I fix this?

The base class is just "Account" and looks as follows:

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H_
#define ACCOUNT_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Account
{
    public:
        Account();
        ~Account();

        void SetInfo(string name,
                     int    ID,
                     double balance,
                     int    day,
                     int    month,
                     int    year);
        void SetInfo(double balance);
        void Deposit(double deposit);
        void Withdrawal(double withdrawal);
        void Transfer(Account* receiver,
                      double transferAmt);

        string GetName() const;
        int    GetID() const;
        double GetBalance() const;
        int    GetDay() const;
        int    GetMonth() const;
        int    GetYear() const;

        string DisplayDay() const;

        Account* next;
        Account* prev;

    private:
        string acctName;
        int    acctID;
        double acctBalance;
        int    dayOpened;
        int    monthOpened;
        int    yearOpened;
};

#endif /* ACCOUNT_H_ */
```

I'm assuming I need to declare the pointers as public because whenever I put them under protected, I can't compile. I also made sure I initialized next and prev in the constructor:

```
#include "Derived.h"

Account::Account()
{
    acctName.clear();
    acctID      = 0;
    acctBalance = 0.00;
    dayOpened   = 1;
    monthOpened = 1;
    yearOpened  = 1901;

    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}
```

Note: Derived.h is the header file of the child classes, containing Account.h. I also didn't declare any pointers within the child classes. Perhaps I'm just using them wrong but, here is main:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "Derived.h"

int main()
{
    Account* member;
    Account* head;
    Account* search;

    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    string inputFileName;
    string outputFileName;

    int    openMonth;
    int    openDay;
    int    openYear;
    int    memberID;
    double memberBalance;
    string transactionType;

    member = new Savings("NAME",
                         1212,
                         300.00,
                         30,
                         4,
                         2012,
                         .10);

    head   = member;
    search = head;
    member = member->next;


    member = new Checking("NAME",
                          2323,
                          50.00,
                          30,
                          4,
                          2012);

    member = member->next;

    member = new MoneyMarket("NAME",
                             3434,
                             100.00,
                             30,
                             4,
                             2012,
                             .20);

    member->next = NULL;

    cout << "Enter an input file name: ";
    getline(cin, inputFileName);
    cout << "Enter an output file name: ";
    getline(cin, outputFileName);

    inFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());
    outFile.open(outputFileName.c_str());

    while(inFile)
    {
        inFile >> openDay;
        inFile >> openMonth;
        inFile >> openYear;
        inFile >> memberID;
        inFile >> memberBalance;
        getline(inFile, transactionType);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        while(search->next != NULL && search->GetID() != memberID)
        {
            cerr << "test";
        }

    }
```

Object oriented programming is very new to me so forgive me if this is kind of a dumb question.

Comment: Binary not found implies there was a compile/link error that prevented the executable from being generated.  Did you look at the filesystem?  Is there an executable?

Comment: @RetiredNinja How would I check this?

Comment: What did you do to build the application, and how do you know it completed successfully?

Comment: @MarkLakata I know it completed successfully because I didn't get any compile time errors. And to build the application, I just used Eclipse's standard commands for saving all, building, and running.

Comment: I mean, from Eclipse, what menu command or key stroke did you use to build the application? And what window showed zero errors during the link stage?

Comment: Put `#if 0` after `int main()` and `#endif` before the closing `}`, build it and see if it runs. If it doesn't run, it has nothing to do with you C++ code.

Comment: I used Ctrl+B to build. And normally if there's a compile time error, it'll show up by the name of the file where the error exists.

Comment: @MarkLakata I did this and I got a binary launch failure.

Comment: Create a new project (with just `main()`) and verify it builds. Then copy and paste your code from this broken project into it.

Comment: @MarkLakata That fixed it. Really weird..